# Can't use "custom" SSL certificate in proxy server (built-in works)

Tags: ssl, proxy, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to configure Titanium web proxy to use my own SSL certificate (ok and I need to generate my certificate(s) again because i just deleted them).

> **First**: my use case works fine, I need to intercept `https` traffic and
>   I setup Titanium in a .NET Core app. It generated and
>   configured/installed come "rootCert.pfx" file and I can intercept
>   `https` traffic.
>
> ref: https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/wiki#custom-root-certificates

The referenced page says I can set a **custom root certificate** using the `RootCertificate` property on the proxyserver.

So I create a certificate:

`openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt`

convert it to a `pfx`:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt`

copy it to the output directory and configure it as `RootCertificate`.

But now my browser says for any https request:

> **ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**

I tried doubleclicking and installing the `crt` file but this doesn't help..

Am a little lost here as to where I should place what certificate. To make things more complicated for me to understand there is also a `GenericCertificate` property on the `ExplicitProxyEndPoint` class... If I configure the root certificate there then my browser returns:

> **ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

Any guidance or tips would be greatly appreciated!

## Second try (spoiler: failed again)

1. Create *CA key*: **customCA.key**

   > `openssl genrsa -des3 -out customCA.key 2048`
2. Create *CA root certificate*: **customCA.pem**

   > `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key customCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out customCA.pem`
3. Trust *CA root certificate*: Import **customCA.pem**

   > [image: Import certificate here] [image: Certificate properties]
4. Create *localhost key*: **localhost.key**

   > `openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048`
5. Create *localhost sign request*: **localhost.csr**

   > `openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out localhost.csr`
6. Create *custom ext options*: **localhost.ext**

```
    [ req ]
    default_bits        = 2048 
    default_keyfile     = customCA.pem 
    distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
    req_extensions          = v3_req
    x509_extensions         = v3_ca

    [req_distinguished_name]
    C = [Press Enter to Continue]
    C_default = US 
    C_min = 2 
    C_max = 2 

    O = [Press Enter to Continue]
    O_default = default 

    0.OU=[Press Enter to Continue]
    0.OU_default = default 
    1.OU=[Press Enter to Continue]
    1.OU_default = PKI 
    2.OU=[Press Enter to Continue] 
    2.OU_default = ABCD
    commonName = Public FQDN of server 
    commonName_max = 64
    emailAddress = [Press Enter to Continue] 
    emailAddress_default = myEmail@email.com

    [ v3_req ]
    basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
    keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment

    [ v3_ca ]
    subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
    authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
    subjectAltName         = email:myEmail@email.com
    issuerAltName          = issuer:copy
```

7. Create *signed localhost certificate*: **localhost.crt**

   > `openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA customCA.pem -CAkey customCA.key -CAcreateserial -out localhost.crt -days 1825 -sha256 -extfile localhost.ext`
8. Convert *signed localhost certificate from `crt` to `pfx`*: **localhost.pfx**

   > `openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt`

**Now if I specify `localhost.pfx` as the `RootCertificate` for the proxyserver (which i'm assuming will be trusted due to the fact that it is signed by `customCA` which is a trusted authority) i still get:**

> **ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**

I'm starting to get confused about `RootCertificate` and `Certificate Authority`. It seems that the proxyserver requires a mix of both?

Comment: Key Usage cert attribute needs to include cert signing, and Basic Constraints attribute needs to include SubjectType=CA

Comment: "Key Usage" is shows in the Certificate Management snap in to allow "All purposes" which includes signing... However the certificate generated by Titanium only allows for "Server Authentication" and that one works...

Comment: The root cert is the CA's cert.  But I see a CA=false in there.

Comment: I changed it to CA=TRUE, but it still shows: `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`